# ASP.net: Read HTML and ASP.net Pages to Strings?

Tags: asp.net, html, parsing

I am trying to write an aspx page which will crawl through a directory and find all the files contained within. I think I have that part down.

Is it possible to read to a string without first creating .txt files from the html and asp pages I'm reading through? I don't want to create a ton of new files and then end up having to delete them later.

Ultimately, I'm trying to develop a tool to search through an entire directory and find all the image tags which have empty alt attributes or no alt attributes. I wrote some jQuery which can find the tags, and I have also written the part that searches through a directory.

Comment: Do you just want to read the html files that you have discovered?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to find all files in directory, then load specified file into string object?

Comment: That's essentially it. I want to find all the files in a directory, read them to a string, and then check the string for image tags that fit my criteria. I have the directory part and the image tag search part more or less done. Can I read files to a string without first copying their contents to a .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Example:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/load-text-file-to-string/
(this example shows how to work with .txt files, but I believe if you can put any other extension)

Getting all files:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

Edit: and don't forgot about encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file on your filesystem, you can simply read it - if you know it is a textual format, you need to use a stream with the correct encoding to do this.

Since you are reading and querying HTML, I suggest using a library that is specifically written for this task - the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - you can give it the path to the HTML file and then query it for all `img` elements. The source download comes with sample projects that will show you how to achieve this and other tasks.

Comment: Will HTML Agility Pack read asp pages? I'm assuming yes but I couldn't find an answer with some quick googling.

Comment: @MNRSullivan - Not the source files. If you mean pages that you see in your browser that were created with ASP.NET, then yes, so long as you see HTML.

Answer (score 0):

sure, why not save to environment variables, no fuss, no mess. so try something like this:
will take apart an html or asp file and save to an array of variables, i have shown you how to put it back together as well.
let me know how if this is a solution for you

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
echo.
set count=0
if exist newfile.html del newfile.html
:: to unassemble
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filename.html) do (
    echo %%a
    set /a count=count + 1
    set htmllinenum!count!=%%a
)& set finalcount=!count!
:: to assemble
for /l %%a in (1,1,%finalcount%) do (
    echo !htmllinenum%%a!>>newfile.html
)
notepad newfile.tmp
    set count=0
if exist newfile.asp del newfile.asp
:: to unassemble
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filename.asp) do (
    echo %%a
    set /a count=count + 1
    set asplinenum!count!=%%a
)& set finalcount=!count!
:: to assemble
for /l %%a in (1,1,%finalcount%) do (
    echo !asplinenum%%a!>>newfile.asp
)
notepad newfile.asp
```